# Speeding up code for lattice generation

Tags: performance-tuning

Below is a lattice point generation code I write

```
Clear[lattice];
lattice[basisvec_List, numofcell_List, base_List] := 
  Flatten[Transpose[# + Transpose[base]] & /@ (Tuples[Range /@ numofcell].basisvec), 1]
```

to use it for example,

```
a = 1.;
list = lattice[{{3 a, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3] a}}, {5, 
     5}, {{0, 0}, {a, 0}, {-a/2, Sqrt[3] a/2}, {3 a/2, 
      Sqrt[3] a/2}}];
```

generate a honeycomb lattice

[image]

To generate 4000000 points,

```
lattice[{{3 a, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3] a}}, {1000, 
    4000}, {{0, 0}, {a, 0}, {-a/2, Sqrt[3] a/2}, {3 a/2, 
     Sqrt[3] a/2}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

it takes 4.52389 sec

This is the fastest code I could write at the moment. I also tried `compile` as follows

```
latticecom = 
  Compile[{{basisvec, _Real, 2}, {numofcell, _Integer, 
     1}, {base, _Real, 2}}, Clear[lattice];
   Flatten[
    Transpose[# + Transpose[base]] & /@ (Tuples[
        Range /@ numofcell].basisvec), 1], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

But it will gives errors when using it

> CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with
>   uncompiled evaluation. >>

**Can someone explain this?**

I also write a fortran version to test how efficiency can differ between fortran and mathematica. It turns out that fortran done the same thing almost instantly.

**So I want to see how this code could be great improved to be comparable to fortran.**

Comment: `Tuples[]` is not compilable, no?

Comment: @J.M. Yeah I know, but `Tuples` is not in a loop, so I think it is harmless

Comment: Anyway, try this: `lattice[basisvec_?MatrixQ, numofcell_?VectorQ, base_?MatrixQ] := Flatten[Through[(TranslationTransform /@ (Tuples[Range /@ numofcell].basisvec))[base]], 1]`.

Comment: @J.M. Nope, much slower than mine :）

Comment: This should be pretty fast, then: `lattice[basisvec_List, numofcell_List, base_List] := Flatten[Outer[Plus, Tuples[Range /@ numofcell].basisvec, base, 1], 1]`.

Comment: @J.M. still 10 times slower than mine : )

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Good thing I didn't post an answer, then. :D

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your trying. Let us wait other solutions ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be faster, dealing with the x and y coordinate lists separately:

```
lattice2[basisvec_List, numofcell_List, base_List] :=
 Module[{x, y, basex, basey},
  {x, y} = Transpose[Tuples[Range /@ numofcell].basisvec];
  {basex, basey} = Transpose[base];
  Transpose[{Join @@ ((x + #) & /@ basex), Join @@ ((y + #) & /@ basey)}]]
```

Comment: my test shows that yours and mine are almost the same efficiency. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I keep improving my version

**First version **, by separate `Transpose[base]` and Change the way `Transpose` act, time reduce from 4.52389 sec to 2.57898 sec

```
Clear[lattice];
lattice[basisvec_List, numofcell_List, base_List] :=
 (tmptmp = Transpose[base];
  Flatten[
   Transpose[(# + tmptmp) & /@ (Tuples[
        Range /@ numofcell].basisvec), {1, 3, 2}], 1])
```

**second version**, reverse vector adding order, time reduce from 4.52389 sec to 1.28168 sec

```
Clear[lattice];
lattice[basisvec_List, numofcell_List, base_List] :=
 (basetmp = N@base;
  tmptmp2 = Transpose[Tuples[Range /@ numofcell].basisvec];
  Flatten[Transpose[(# + tmptmp2) & /@ basetmp, {1, 3, 2}], 1]
```

Notice that I add `basetmp = N@base`, because I found that if this is not added, there will be unpacking process. This is because there is exact zero in `base`. **But don't know why the "first version" has no unpacking problem**. What is more, if we change `Flatten[Transpose[(# + tmptmp2) & /@ basetmp, {1, 3, 2}], 1]` to `Flatten[Transpose[(# + tmptmp2)] & /@ basetmp, 1]`, **it will get unpacking again, don't know why!!!**

And finally, still cannot catch fortran.